# Offset on JQuery accordion content when click on accordion header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to play with `offset` and `animate` to scroll to the content of the `accordion`, when user click on his header. [Live here](https://www.fundacioncb.es/becas-ofertadas/).

I have 30 accordion on my page, so I tried this:

```
  $(".ui-accordion").on("click",function(){
       var $acc = $(this);
        $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $acc.offset().top
  }, 500);
    });
```

And this:

```
  $(".ui-accordion-header").on("click",function(){
       var $acc =  $(this).next(".ui-accordion-content");
        $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $acc.offset().top
  }, 500);
    });
```

But didn't worked, I didn't saw console error too. I tried to insert an `alert` example on the function to show if is a problem of the `scrolltop` feature, but alert didn't worked too, so I think that the click function is not working.

**HTML structure of one of the item:**

```
<div class="column">
<div class="text-box">
<h3>Titulación</h3>
<p>Información y documentación / Comunicación Audiovisual</p>
<h3>Puesto a desempeñar</h3>
<p>Gestor documental/ Editor medios audiovisuales</p>
<h3>Tipo de beca</h3>
<p>Entidad sin ánimo de lucro: 1 año media jornada sin compromiso</p>
</div>
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
  <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-corner-top ui-accordion-header-collapsed ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Más información</h3>
  <div class="ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; height: 518px;">
  <h3>Breve descripción del puesto</h3>
<p>Recopilación y clasificación de material digitalizado del archivo de la Fundación/ Edición audiovisual</p>
<h3>Empresa</h3>
<p>Fundación Centro de Estudios Presidente Rodríguez Ibarra (FUNDCERI)</p>
<h3>Localización del puesto</h3>
<p>Sede Fundación</p>
<h3>Horario de trabajo</h3>
<p>Mañana</p>
<div class="boton-proyecto-inicia"><a class="boton-solicitudes" title="Inscripción Premios Emprendimiento" href="https://www.fundacioncb.es/inscripcion-premios-emprendimiento/">Inscribirse</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working.
But keep in mind that you should run you JavaScript code AFTER the dom elements been rendered. or use `on` to do live binding.
Change your code something like this:

```
 $("html").on("click", ".ui-accordion", function(){
   var $acc = $(this);
   $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $acc.offset().top}, 
    500);});
```

Comment: I used it but still without working. I updated the live page.

Comment: seems you are putting your javascript code before the `body` tag, you can put before the end of your `</body>` tag. then your old code will works too. The issue is your selector is empty if you put it before the `body` tag. that's why you need document.ready.